# References on second-order quantifier elimination and related topics

Tags: reference-request, first-order-logic

I was wondering whether something like elimination of second-order quantifiers exist, and indeed it seems it does. I've found there's a workshop on this topic, and [the webpage](http://2021.soqe.org) describes exactly what I need:

> Second-order quantifier elimination (SOQE) is the problem of
> equivalently reducing a formula with quantifiers upon second-order
> objects such as predicates to a formula in which these quantified
> second-order objects no longer occur.

Unexpectedly (at least for me) the topic seems to be related to a lot of other things that I need for what I'm doing: Craig interpolants, uniform interpolants, Beth definability.

So is there a reference (maybe a survey?) about second-order quantifier elimination and its connections with the topics above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since there are no answer I think it may be useful to post [what I've found](http://collegepublications.co.uk/logic/mlf/?00009):

Dov M. Gabbay, Renate A. Schmidt, Andrzej Szalas
*Second-Order Quantifier Elimination - Foundations, Computational Aspects and Applications*.
Studies in logic : Mathematical logic and foundations 12, College Publications 2008,
ISBN 978-1-904987-56-7, pp. I-VIII, 1-308

It seems quite complete and well-written. That's what I was looking for.